# How can I select rows that are since between last hour and last year?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

This query restricts selecting since last hour:

```
... WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```

And this one does that for last year:

```
... WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

How can I write that `WHERE` clause to restricts selecting between *last hour* and *last year* ?

Comment: `Between.`   Or you could use CompareDate > some date and compareDate < otherdate... that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `between`:

```
WHERE from_unixtime(date_time) BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 1 year) AND (now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

---

comment followup:

```
mysql> select now() - interval 1 year, date_sub(now(), interval 1 year);
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| now() - interval 1 year | date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 2015-09-09 09:25:59     | 2015-09-09 09:25:59              |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, but look, the value of `date_time` column is a integer like this: `1473434534` .. So I guess you have to use `unix_timestamp`

Comment: yeah, just realized that. added the from_unixtime() call.

Comment: And what about `DATE_SUB()` function? I don't need it?

Comment: works out the same as the interval notation, really. `date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)` and `now() - interval 1 year` are functionally identical.

Comment: Ah I see. thx for your editing. My last question, why did you use `from_unixtime()` instead of `unix_timestamp()` ?

Comment: from_unixtime() = timestamp -> mysql date. unixtimestamp = mysql date -> timestamp. rather than converting both of the year/hour calculations to timestamp, I convert your stored timestamp to a mysql date/time.

Comment: Oh ... wise .. thank you .. Just for my information, Can I also remove that `from_unixtime()` and wrap both of the year/hour calculations into `unix_timestamp()` instead, right?

Comment: yup. it's just a reversal of logic. either you compare mysql date to mysql date, or timestamp to timestamp. but timestamp to date won't work. mysql "knows" what a date/time is, but a timestamp is just an integer. it won't autoconvert an int to a mysql date/time.

Comment: Why do you think is using `from_unixtime` better than `unix_timestamp`? You know, if you put a column into a function, then the query doesn't use any index. So using `unix_timestamp` for the other side of your condition would be much better than wrapping `date_time` column into `from_unixtime`. **methinks**

Answer (score 1):

```
where date_time between unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) and unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```